# C++ Как сделать функцию в функции

Tags: c++, функции, классы

Всем доброго дня. У меня такой вопрос.
 У меня есть структура под название Книга(Book) в пространстве имен Library и мне надо сделать поиск по имени книги и автору, и чтобы не писать отдельно 3 функции (интерфейс, поиск по имени, поиск по названию) хочу реализовать что-то в этом роде:
 
`Library::FindBook().ByName();` 
Такую запись я видел в сторонних библиотеках по типу SFML или OpenGL, так что надеюсь мне помогут :) 
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Делаете функцию которая вернёт класс, а в класс можно добавить метод `ByName()`. Как реализовать - если вы знакомы с классами - без проблем реализуете. Если нет - сначало ознакомтесь с классами.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот [небольшой пример](https://ideone.com/BDIQzG) для понимания самой идеи.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class C {
    public:
        C& first()  {
            cout << "first\n" ;
            return *this;
            };
        C& second() {
            cout << "second\n";
            return *this;
            };
        C& third()  {
            cout << "third\n" ;
            return *this;
            };
    };


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    C c;
    c.first().second().third();
    }
```

Здесь все функции - члены одного класса. Но это не обязательно:

```
class A {
    public:
        void aa() {
            cout << "A:aa()\n";
            }
    };

class B {
        A a;
    public:
        A& bb() {
            cout << "B:bb()\n";
            return a;
            }
    };

class C {
        B a;
    public:
        B& cc() {
            cout << "C:cc()\n";
            return a;
            }
    };


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    C c;
    c.cc().bb().aa();
    }
```

Главное - вернуть объект класса, для которого делается следующий вызов.

Если возвращать указатели, может быть такая цепочка:

```
c->cc()->bb()->aa();
```